# how to get local date/time format?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get systems local date/time format and display date from database on this same format. e.g if system date format is  like **Month dd/yyyy** and date stored in  database is **mm/dd/yyyy** format then I need to get local date/time format and convert my stored date into local format. 
HTML5 input `type="date"` this takes default systems date/time format and show date in same format. how can I do this with `jquery` or `javascript`.

Comment: So what is your question? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to read local date/time format and display stored date in that format. I am not able to get system date format like mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469436/how-format-javascript-date-with-regard-to-the-browser-culture

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Get system short date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210058/javascript-get-system-short-date-format)

Comment: I hope you're not storing a date as a `mm/dd/yyyy` string in your database. You should be storing it as a `date` (or `datetime`) - the ANSI SQL format  for these is `YYYY-MM-DD` (of course this does not address your question about locale settings)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object:

```
var date = new Date(yearFromDb, monthFromDb, dayFromDb);
date.toLocaleDateString();
```

**EDIT**

It seems that the above method is not consistent between different browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox). Therefore, I think your only option is to get the formatted date string from server side.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Vphd/2/) that shows a cross-browser way of getting the users locale, if you can use this to get a formatted date string in the current locale from the backend (if any).

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

Comment: Its working but its showing different format in chrome and mozilla, like in mozilla its showing Monday July 7 2013 and in chrome it is showing 7/15/2013. My local date/time format is mm/dd/yyyy. so do I have any other function which can return same format on all browser.

Comment: I don't have Firefox installed, but it is possible that there are user preferences in the browsers configuration that override the default locale. Anyway, toLocaleDateString() should return a formatted date according to the user preferences.

Comment: I checked with chromes setting but it does not taking any change, it still showing date in mm/dd/yyyy. even if I change my system date format(dd/mmm/yy) it is still showing date in mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Yes I did some additional tests and chrome always outputs the same. If you read the documentation of `toLocaleDateString()`, you'll find out that you can pass additional options. But IE and Chrome seem to ignore them. Are you using any kind of server-side script (PHP/ASP.NET, ...)?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC4 and one more thing i am changing date format through control panel(in Region and Language) will toLocaleDateString() take those change?