# Date format conversion in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I am using a form ,from which the user can select the datetime from datetime picker in `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` format. Now I want to convert the format to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format to store in mysql table.

I tried with moment js like this

```
console.log(moment(status.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

where status.date I will post from a form where the user selects datetime from datetimepicker.

Please help

Comment: Why convert to string? Just give `node-mysql` a `Date` object in the prepared statement.

Comment: Check out the formats http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: @amadan, the backend is already built in php codeigniter, now we are waiting api's in nodejs. So we want to convert to standard mysql format.

Comment: @SwarajGiri there we can change the format, but im giving the date from form, so I should be able to change the format of the post value.

Comment: If you get in a string and want to output a string, you can remove any external library requirement by just rearranging the parts: `s.replace(/(^\d\d)(-\d\d-)(\d{4})(.+$)/,'$3$2$1$4')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this instead of having some modules.

```
var fd = status.date;
var fromDate = fd.split(" ");
console.log(formatDate(fromDate[0],fromDate[1] + " " + fromDate[2]));//
```

and add these functions there.

```
function formatDate(date, time2) {
    var from = date.split("-");
    var f = from[2] + "-" + from[1] + "-" + from[0];
    var time1 = time(time2);

    return f + " " + time1;
}

function time(time) {
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
    if ((AMPM == "PM" || AMPM == "pm") && hours < 12)
        hours = hours + 12;
    if ((AMPM == "AM" || AMPM == "am") && hours == 12)
        hours = hours - 12;
    var sHours = hours.toString();
     if (hours < 10)
        sHours = "0" + sHours;
    if (minutes < 10)
        sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
   return (sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
```

}

Comment: But, is there any inbuilt method to do this instead of writing code on our own??

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to ISOString first and then eliminate unwanted things by `replace` method.

```
var date = new Date();
date.toISOString().replace(/T/, " ").replace(/\..+/,'')
```

[source: chbrown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645994/node-js-how-to-format-a-date-string-in-utc/13219636#13219636)

Comment: Not sure that will suit. It returns the time as UTC. The OP seems to want local, though not stated explicitly. I seem to recall that not all implementations return the decimal seconds, but not certain about that (and may not be an issue with node.js).

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of [Prateek Jain's ISOString method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32217734/9723036), we can use `toLocaleString` to obtain the **local time** in ISO format.

One needs to shop around the base format provided by `toLocaleString` according to different regions. The format closest to ISO is `en-CA` (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69044670/9723036) for all the region-based format). We then use the option `{hour12: false}` to convert to 24-hour notation.

```js
const d = new Date();
d.toLocaleString('en-CA', {hour12: false}).replace(/, /, ' ');
```