# How to convert a date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to convert the date format '23 MAY 2022' into 23/05/2022 in javascript?

Comment: use moment library

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi MomentJS is no longer recommended by the MomentJS team.

Comment: Why do you want to convert 23 to 25?

Comment: @AdamOrłowski I am sorry It was an typing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60858473/17757846

```
const newDate = new Date("23 MAY 2022").toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit",
  day: "2-digit",
});;
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use momentjs

[momentjs format syntax](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/)

for your case: `moment('23 MAY 2022').format("DD/MM/YYYY")`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon), an evolution of moment.js.

You can use [`DateTime.fromFormat()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat) to parse the input string, then use [`DateTime.toFormat()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoformat) to output the desired result:

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const input = '23 MAY 2022';
const dt = DateTime.fromFormat(input, 'dd MMM yyyy');
const result = dt.toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```