# How to set the date format of the date displayed in kendo datepicker to the same format as the system?

Tags: javascript, date, kendo-ui

I'm using the `kendo datePicker` in my web application.

The date displayed in it has the format `MM/DD/YYYY` by default.

I would like to get the format of the date used by the operating system or the browser and apply it on the `kendo datePicker`.

Is there a method or function in *javascript* that can provide this please?

Comment: Which library are you using ? jQueryUI ? Bootstrap DatePicker ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give me any code, you could try this:

```
    td = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    td = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
   $(document).ready(function() {
                    var today = td,
                        birthdays = [
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 11),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 6),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 27),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 3),
                           new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 22)
                        ];

                    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
                        value: today,
                        dates: birthdays,
                         ....});
```

DatePicker Code adapted from [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/template)

**EDIT:** I've noticed now you've asked about system date.
 I've searched a bit and found out this method `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`

Acording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469436/how-format-javascript-date-with-regard-to-the-browser-culture) you get the formats:

e.g. for me on 13 December, 2011:

1. Safari returns 13 December 2001
2. Firefox 12/13/2011
3. Opera Tuesday December 13, 2011
4. Chrome Tuesday, December 13, 2011
5. IE 6 Tuesday, 13 December, 2011

Yet, I didn't tested it, so please provide me with evidence in case I'm wrong

hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You should use the current culture to determine the format, using [Kendo Globalization](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview).

Determine the current culture:

```
@{
    var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
}
```

Add the Kendo culture scripts:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.culture." + culture + ".min.js")"></script>
```

Then either apply current culture to all widgets:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    kendo.culture("@culture");
</script>
```

...or, hard-code on per-widget basis.

```
$("#firstDate").kendoDatePicker({
    culture: "en-GB",
    //....
});
```

**List of widgets which depends on the current culture**

- Calendar
- DatePicker
- TimePicker
- DateTimePicker
- NumericTextBox
- MaskedTextBox (globalized mask literals)
- Scheduler
- Gantt
- All widgets that support date or numeric formatting.

**globalize.js:**

Note that when globalize.js is registered before Kendo UI scripts, then Kendo UI will use globalize.js features instead of Kendo UI Globalization.