# Convert UTC datetime string to browser based timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

Is there a way to convert a `UTC` string of the format ***"11/30/2016 3:05:24 AM"*** to browser based timezone(say `PST`) in javascript without using third-party libraries/scripts like moment.js ?

Example - If the timezone is `IST`(Indian Standard Time) which is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of `UTC` the output should be ***11/30/2016 8:35:24 AM***

Comment: You can check for `date.toLocaleString()` but I'd suggest using `moment`.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469436/how-format-javascript-date-with-regard-to-the-browser-culture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be best if you use moment.

```
var localTimeInUTC  = moment.utc('11/30/2016 3:05:24 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss A').toDate();
localTime = moment(localTimeInUTC).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A');
console.log(localTime); // It will be in your browser timezone
```

in simple with moment.

```
moment.utc(utcDateTime, utcDateTimeFormat).local().format(specifiedFormat)
```

Okay Now you cleared that you want to do without third party libraries then also it is possible.

1. Take local timezone offset
2. create date object from your UTC string
3. Add your local timezone offset into that

or Simple way without thirdparty library

```
var dateStr = '11/30/2016 3:05:24 AM';
var date = new Date(dateStr + ' UTC');
console.log(date.toString());
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z6dfbvx3/)

Comment: I have edited the question. Can we get the datetime string in the same format based on timezone without using other third-party libraries like moment ?

Comment: @Ashley Yeah, You can check my edited answer with moment.

Comment: It uses moment but.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Also using date.toLocaleString() gives the datetime string in locale browser culture like 11/30/2016 8:35:24 AM.  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kvtv4unq/1/) here.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```js
var dp = "11/30/2016 3:05:24 AM".split(/[/: ]/);
var dateLocale = new Date(Date.UTC(dp[2], dp[0]-1, dp[1], (dp[3]%12 + (dp[6]=='PM' ? 12 : 0)), dp[4], dp[5]));
console.log(dateLocale.toString());
```

Split the dates in components and pass the individual parts in `Date.UTC` function which returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. See [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Create a new date object passing this value and it will return the date in local timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Also using date.toLocaleString() gives the datetime string in locale browser culture like 11/30/2016 8:35:24 AM.  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kvtv4unq/1/) here.